# Youtube CC_lang_pref doesn't seem to be working

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to embed a video and have the spanish subtitles play by default.
cc_load_policy=1 works just fine.
cc_lang_pref=es does not seem to do anything.

I have tried ?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=es and the subtitles come up automatically but they are English
I have tried ?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=es&autoplay=1 and again, the English subtitles come right up, and the autoplay parameter makes the video start as soon as the page loads, but cc_lang_pref doesn't do anything.

I have tried replacing the "_" with _ and I am not getting anywhere.  Has anyone made this parameter work?